# Recommendations for FTP hosting

Tags: hosting, ftp, web-hosting

We are currently using a local ISP to host a FTP site for exchanging graphics files with our partners.  In total there are around 30 accounts with approximately 17GB of files.

I've been trying to find an alternative hosting solution, but it seems like I'm asking for something impossible within the realm of shared hosting.  One particular host told me that despite their plans offer unlimited space, bandwidth and FTP accounts, doing so is in direct violation of their ToS.

Aside from purchasing a dedicated server or VPS, what options can you recommend for hosting a FTP site?

UPDATE: The prospect of using Amazon S3 sounds great, but products like Jungle Disk are probably out as it would require re-training all of our external partners.  Is there any way to setup a pseudo-FTP server that stores the actual files in the cloud?

Answer (score 1):

I set up an account with DreamHost.com (http://www.dreamhost.com) about a year ago and haven't had any major issues.

They run specials all the time.

I think I paid something like $22.00 for TWO YEARS.

---

UPDATE:

After considering your needs a little more, I have a question.  Does it HAVE to be FTP?  What if you used something like Amazon S3 and JungleDisk?  Then you'd simply pay for what you use every month... (something like 15 cents a gig I think).

Everyone who you'd normally give FTP access to could simply have a JungleDisk client installed and it would be like one giant shared HDD.

http://www.jungledisk.com

Just a thought.

---

UPDATE 2:

Polara,  I took a closer look at their website.  Technically it looks like its NOT covered.

http://dreamhost.com/unlimited.html

Comment: Are they aware that you are using it solely for FTP transfers?  This clause in their ToS has me a little concerned:

The customer agrees to make use of DreamHost Web Hosting servers primarily for the purpose of hosting a website, and associated email functions. Data uploaded must be primarily for this purpose.. DreamHost Web Hosting servers are not intended as a data backup or archiving service.

Comment: If it was my own stuff it wouldn't be a problem.  For my employers use OTOH, I'm taking a big risk if it can be shut down because of Dreamhost's policies.  Good to know that they've been lenient in actual practice.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of Hosted FTP providers that *do* offer this.  I'm confused as to why you're having so many problems finding one.

Here's [one](http://www.instantftpsites.com/) as an example.  Never used them, but they offer hosted FTP services with up to 100gb/180 accounts, with "unlimited ftp traffic".

Of course, even your "unlimited" broadband provider at home has AUP/ToS restrictions in place, but they need to do this to cover them from abuse.  Maybe signing up for a higher tier packer (one of the Dev packages) would ensure a more lenient posture from the AUP/ToS perspective.

Comment: The link you provided has plans that start around $12/mo for 500 MB, but quickly escalate based on disk space.  Their 20 GB plan is $219/mo.  Still less than what I'm currently paying but a huge leap from the $10/mo "unlimited" web hosts.

Answer (score 0):

The package I have with 1and1 gives me 250GB of disk space with 2.5TB of bandwidth monthly.  I frequently transfer large files to and from using FTP (5-10GB a month on average), plus my websites with no problems.

Its the business package: http://order.1and1.com/xml/order/Hosting for $9.99/month.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use a product like [Basecamp](http://basecamphq.com/signup).

It is $100/month for up to 20 GB. The files can be organized and you can even have discussions around them.

The primary purpose is for managing simple projects but it does handle files quite well.

Your biggest issue might be loading the initial files in.